# Determining whether a linear combination exists with constraints on the coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a vector $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n $ and a set of vectors $V = \{\vec{v}_i | \vec{v}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, which may be linearly dependent on each other.

Presume that I know that $\vec{x}$ lies in the space spanned by $V$.  I now am interested in determining if I can form a linear combination of vectors in $V$ to get $x$ such that the coefficients all have magnitude less than or equal to 1 (or some other constant).

What methods exist to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you let the columns of the $n \times m$ matrix $A$ be the $m$ vectors in $V$, you are looking for a solution $z \in \mathbb{R}^m$ to $Az=x$
such that $\|z\|_\infty := \max_i |z_i| \le 1$. You might cast this as an optimization problem i.e.
$$\min_z \|z\|_\infty \text{ s.t. } Az = x.$$

Comment: Such an optimization problem can be written as a [linear program](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) and solved very efficiently.